# Book about parastic bees

Tags: story-identification, books

I am looking for a book about parasitic bees that lay eggs in people and mammals. Any ideas? I'm not sure if this book is science fiction.

Comment: It _needs_ to be science-fiction for it to be [on-topic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: If you search for parasitic wasps, on the other hand, you're in for a lovely(?) few hours/days!

Answer (score 2):

Could it be that you're thinking of Atsuko Asano's novel series *[No. 6](https://animanga.fandom.com/wiki/No._6)*?

> No. 6 is a nine-volume novel series written by Atsuko Asano and published by Kodansha between October 2003 and June 2011.

....

> The story takes place in an ideal city known as "No. 6". Shion, a boy raised in the elite and privileged environment of his home, gives shelter to another boy, who only gives his name as 'Nezumi', during the former's 12th birthday. After spending a rainy night with his new friend, Shion discovers the next morning that Nezumi has left and disappeared without a trace. 4 years later, Shion experiences a spate of incidents around him in which a deadly infection by parasitic bees leaves its victims to age rapidly. Not willing to be confined inside an adjustment facility for the rest of his life, he decides to run away from the city, and to the slum-filled West Block, where he meets Nezumi once again.